# Very basic Maven - can't compile

Tags: maven

I'm running the basic `HelloWorld` with a simple Maven project.  The `mvn` compile works fine, then in my `HelloWorld`, I add the `org.slf4j.*` as an import then attempt a one line logger.

When I perform a `mvn compile`, I get a compile error indicating `org.slf4f` is not found.

It should be simple enough, appears the compile is not pointing to the large set of jar's it downloaded on my .m2 drive.  I found the correct jar there.  I'm missing something very basic, in the debugger I see that the `-classpath` does not point to anything other than my java classes (one class, HelloWorld)?  Is there a basic element here I'm missing?

Below is also my pom file and the version also exists in my .m2 repository  I though Maven magically finds these jars in the repository?

```
 [DEBUG] -d C:\TestMaven\target\classes -classpath C:\TestMaven\target\classes; -sourcepath C:\TestMaven\src\main\java; -g -nowarn -target 1.5 -source 1.5
```

```xml
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>org.koushik.javabrains</groupId>
 <artifactId>MavenTestApp</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>  <!-- jar war or ear etc... -->

 <name>MavenTestApp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>  <!-- tells maven when to use this artifact -->
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>  <!-- tells maven when to use this artifact -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `slf4j-api` as a `test` dependency. This means it will only be present in the classpath during execution of the unit tests, not during compilation (refer to [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)).

You need to change the scope to `compile`. Since this is the default scope, we can just omit it.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.12</version>
  <!-- scope compile by default -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: ahhhh, that's it...  I should have seen that...That's the problem with tutorials makes one more complacent..   THANKS!

Comment: @JaySchrock Glad I could help. Consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) this answer if it best answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're following the [standard maven layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) (shown below), you don't need to specify your source and classpath. For simple cases, put your `pom.xml` in the root of your project and just run `mvn test`.

A basic maven project layout:

```
project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |   `-- resources
    `-- test
        `-- java
        `-- resources
```

You'll want to run `mvn install` or something more thereafter, but that should be enough.

If you are still struggling, run the [maven-archetype-quickstart](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/) and move your code into the generated project.